# Problem in the tsconfig.json file when trying to use Jest with Typescript

Tags: typescript, jestjs

The error message I am getting is:

```
File 'd:/Project/server/jest.config.ts' is not under 'rootDir' 
'd:/Project/server/src'. 'rootDir' is expected to contain all source files.
The file is in the program because:
Matched by include pattern '**/*' in 'd:/Project/server/tsconfig.json'
```

My tsconfig.json file is:

```
{
 "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2020",
    "module": "commonjs",

    "rootDir": "./src",
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true
  }
}
```

My jest.config.ts file is:

```
export default {
    clearMocks: true,
    collectCoverage: true,
    coverageDirectory: "coverage",
    coverageProvider: "v8",
    transform: {
        "^.+\\.(t|j)sx?$": ["@swc/jest"],
    },
};
```

I am trying to exactly follow the directives of each documentation.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to move your `jest.config.ts` file inside your `src/` directory in order to work. The error is self explanatory I would say.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I tried to do that, but the problem persisted because I did not Reload Window in VSCode. 
After the window reloaded, this solution worked.

Comment: Nice. Angular has hot reload anyways, so i dont know why you had to reaload the page manually

Answer (score 2):

For future reference, another possible solution would be to simply change

```
"rootDir": "./src",
```

to

```
"rootDir": "./",
```

in the `tsconfig.json` file.

Especially if you don't want to move all your configuration files into the `src/` directory.